LLVM scan-build (ccc-analyzer) cannot find framework headers
I'm trying to perform some static analysis on my code.  I've installed LLVM 19.1.4 via brew.
My Makefile builds correctly.
somnior~/Documents/20191022-Blackmagic/monitor/monitor% make       
/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/19.1.4/bin/clang -O2 -F /Library/Frameworks -c main.m -o main.o
/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/19.1.4/bin/clang  -framework foundation -framework AudioToolbox -F /Library/Frameworks -framework DeckLinkAPI -framework NSDeckLink main.o -o monitor

But running with scan-build says that the headers are not found.
somnior~/Documents/20191022-Blackmagic/monitor/monitor% /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/19.1.4/bin/scan-build make
scan-build: Using '/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/19.1.4/bin/clang-19' for static analysis
/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/19.1.4/bin/../libexec/ccc-analyzer -O2 -F /Library/Frameworks -c main.m -o main.o
main.m:3:9: fatal error: 'NSDeckLink/NSDeckLink.h' file not found
    3 | #import <NSDeckLink/NSDeckLink.h>
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.

I'm not able to use the -I option because of the pseudo directory structure that #import and frameworks use.
Is this a bug or am I missing an option somewhere?
